# What can I do with an Istanbulkart after I hit the 500 lira monthly loading limit?

Tags: public-transport, refunds, istanbul

When travelling in Istanbul, it's possible for up to 5 people to share one Istanbulkart.  However, if you're using the "anonymous" cards you can easily buy from vending machines, for some bizarre reason you can only load 500 lira per card per month, after which you start getting "Aylık Yükleme Miktarı Aşılçak" (Monthly Loading Amount Will Be Exceeded) errors when you try to top up.  And thanks to inflation, 500 TL is not very much at all these days, a single ferry ride from Büyükada to Eminönu racks up 310 TL for a family of four.

Once you hit this limit, **is there anything you can do with the card?**  Or do you just need to eat the 70 TL fee for a new card every time?

Comment: There's lot's of things you could do with the card. Hang it on the wall, send it to a collector, papercrafts, _papier-mâché_ (if it's one of those papery cards), &c. But I get the impression that's not what you're looking for.